# how to access MatDialogConfig from inside of called component?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using MatDialog inside my spa and need to pass MatDialogConfig to the component that has been called. Is there any way?

Comment: [The docs on using MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-) describe how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `componentInstance` of `MatDialogRef<T>`. Just get the dialog's ref to get the `MatDialogRef`:

Method to open dialog:

```ts
openDialog(dialogConfig: MatDialogConfig) {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent);
  // You can rename the dialogConfig instance to whatever you want. See the next code snippet for more info.
  dialogRef.componentInstance.dialogConfig = dialogConfig;
}
```

Dialog component:

```ts
export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  // Rename the property to whatever you want it to be
  dialogConfig: MatDialogConfig;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.dir(`Dialog config: ${this.dialogConfig}`);
  }
}
```